# Affinity Photo | How to Display Primary and Secondary Colors in Toolbar?

Tags: affinity-designer

New to Affinity Photo, simple question, how can I show the primary and secondary colors in the toolbar like in this screenshot?

I tried the customize tools panel under view, checked the studio section, and even dragged the colors from the colors panel onto the toolbar, but still no luck. I'm trying to streamline my workflow, so having it visible on the toolbar would be helpful.

[image: screenshot from a tutorial I'm following]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the bottom of the View menu is an option to Undock the tools. When undocked there's the fast color selector icon:

[image]

BTW. This is the tool palette and its name is "Tools". The toolbar is horizontally just below the menu bar.

Comment: Thanks Zach! I'm able to see the fast color selector icon now.
Is there a way to redock with the fast color selector icon visible as in the screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know it. But Docking and undocking are fast, simply double click the non-icon area of the tool palette.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and terminology tips! I noticed under customize tools that if you display two columns instead of one, it widens the area enough to display the fast selector icon.